# How close alerdialog without buttons

Tags: android

I created a query application database to android and I put a progress bar for the user to see the progress of the search, I put in an alert dialog.

The problem comes next:

-Everything is perfect, the thread activity changes when I tell you, but then to turn back from the AlertDialog activity with the progress bar on the screen are included.

I wanted to know how could I say, without buttons, that when the thread arrives at 4 AlertDialog is closed, since it is pretty bad when you want to make another search, the method code attached running the alerdialog.

```
 private void AlertCargando(){

   final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Buscar.this);

    //Crea el dialogo
    alertDialog.setTitle("Buscando...");

    final ProgressBar barra = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
    barra.setProgress(0);
    barra.setMax(4);
    mProgressStatus = 0;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ComprobarDatos();

            while (mProgressStatus < 4) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mProgressStatus = SumaUno(mProgressStatus);

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        barra.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

                    }
                });
            }

//Here i want close the alerDialog
            if(mProgressStatus == 4){
        startActivity(i);
                               }


        }
    }).start();


    alertDialog.setView(barra);
    // Showing Alert Message

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

and here the metod "SumaUno"

```
private int SumaUno(int numero){

    numero = numero++;

    return numero;
}
```

I remind you that everything works perfectly, I just want to know how close the alerdialog.

THANK YOU =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a `Thread`, instead use an `AsyncTask`. Create and show the `Dialog` in `AsyncTask#onPreExecute()` and call `Dialog#dismiss()` in `AsyncTask#onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Thx a lot =D y see this example and is very easy =D http://miguelangellv.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/creando-tareas-asincronas-en-android-con-asynctask/

Answer (score 0):

Using `AsyncTask` is the best Idea. If you dont want to do that then try following

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.show();
```

you can then call the `alert.cancel()` method on the alert (not the builder)